# Problem with network after malware attack

Tags: windows-xp, networking, malware, services

Im trying to help some friends with a Win XP machine. I got rid of the malware using Malware Bytes, and HiJackThis. But now they(I) have another problem.

When the computer boot into Windows it seems fine.  When I start Internet Explorer the browser window opens just fine, but nothing happens for at minute or two. After the two minutes of waiting, the network icon appears in the taskbar next to the clock, and then everything works.

The computer is connected to the internet using a Ethernet adapter.

I have looked at the Rvent Log and found  an error from **Perfnet** with **eventid 2004**

```
<Provider Name="PerfNet" />  
<EventID Qualifiers="49152">2004</EventID>  
<Level>2</Level>  
<Task>0</Task>  
<Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
```

**What I have tried so far:**

- In the device manager i have uninstalled the Ethernet adapter and installed it again.
- I have uninstalled and installed the Windows File and Printer Sharing service.
- I have verified that both server and workstation services are started.

What should I do next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for all your ideas, however my friend called me the other night to tell me the computer works just perfect now. He claimed not to have changed anything, which just making it all more wierd. But problem solved. Again thank you for your time

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I'd suggest wiping the partitions and reinstalling. You could spend hours trying to clean this up, by which time you could have reinstalled the system from scratch.

Reinstalling is the only guaranteed way of cleaning the malware from the system too.

Educate your friend to not use administrator rights in future, unless of course administrator rights are required, e.g. when installing software.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. A format and a reinstall might be the solution final solution, but I will hate to do it since people always forget to back something up.

Answer (score 1):

Run a MalWareBytes scan (full scan).  You might pick up some registry problems.

Answer (score 1):

it may have done something to the TCP/IP Stack, it may be worth going to the command prompt and typing the following:

> `NETSH INT IP RESET`
>
> `NETSH INT WINSOCK RESET`

Lastly, I would use [Microsoft / Sysinternals Autoruns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx) and just check for any bad entries.

Without seeing the machine, it is hard to really help - but you have tried most of the things I would've. After a virus attack, it is hard to know what is still affected and sometimes a reinstall is best.

[Also, consider reading this guide.](https://superuser.com/questions/100360/what-to-do-if-my-computer-is-infected-by-a-virus-or-a-malware/100370#100370)

Answer (score 1):

Have you try another browser like firefox or opera? Or any other networked software? If you don't have one you could just use `ping www.google.com` in a command prompt

If it's IE only related you could try going in `Tools > Manage Addons` to disable everything suspect. And this tool [Fix IE](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/repair-internet-explorer-with-fix-ie-utility) could help too

If it's a all network issue:

In a command prompt (runned as administrator):

**netsh int ip reset intipreset.log**
  Reset the TCP/IP stack = reset/rewrite the following TCP/IP-related registry keys:

```
    * SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\
    * SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\DHCP\Parameters\
```

*You may need to re-configure your TCP/IP settings after that*

**netsh winsock reset**
Repair winsock It removes all Winsock LSP (Layered Service Providers) previously installed, including the potential malfunctioned LSP that causes loss of network packets transmission failure.

*So all previously-installed LSPs (antivirus/firewall) may need to be reinstalled*

**netsh interface reset all**
Reset all interfaces: 6to4, HTTPSTunnel, ipv4, ipv6, isatap, portproxy, tcp, teredo

*I don't know exactly what you risk to do it (not much I think, except reinstalling/reconfiguring network related software & windows parameters...)*

Comment: Thank you. Ill give your suggeswtions ago when i come near the computer again

Answer (score 1):

have you tried to connect to anything without using IE.
e.g open a command prompt and ping www.google.com or even just the router to start with.
I do tend to aggree with the consensus though, if its been a paticularly nasty malware attck it is sometimes better just to backup data and do a clean install. it can sometimes be a blessing (I know this sounds odd, but you can totally re-evaluate everything you use and what you need don't need. Re-layout the partitions of the drive etc)

Comment: Ive tried to open outlooks express, but it simply doest show up until a have waited a minute or two